# Why is call to factory in angular occuring 3 times on load?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a factory in my angular code that I call from my controller like this:

```
$scope.result = themefactory.someMethod();
console.log('results are ' + $scope.result);
```

When I open my page and look at my console I'm seeing that this runs 3 times on page load? It seems silly to make the call 3 times? How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you are not loading the controller twice like this:

```
.state('signin', {
    url: '/entrar',
    templateUrl: 'auth/views/_login.html',
    controller: 'TestController'
  })
```

And like this: `ng-controller="TestController"`

That might eliminate one execution, need more details for the other...

Comment: Ahh yes, I see that one of the 3 was from the app.js declaration. There were still 2 occurring but it turns out I was calling the controller from a child view. Figured it out, thanks!

Comment: Im glad it helped, can you accept my answer pls? :)